# Invalid read of size 1 Valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

So I got this error from when using Valgrind: Invalid read of size 1. This is the parts of the program where the error appears. As for what the program does. The msgArr are a bunch of integers stored as strings. Then I extracted int value from **msgArr and use that as indexes to get characters from **wordArr. Characters that i have gotten, i stored them  **decoded. And then i used a void function to print out the content of **decoded which it prints out correctly but i still haven't figured out why this error occurred. Can you explain? Also what is (vg_replace_malloc.c:762)?
EDIT: line 285: main() calls decodeMsg(), line 242: decodeMsg() calls decodeWords().

```
==31064== Invalid read of size 1
==31064==    at 0x4E84029: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1635)
==31064==    by 0x4E8A458: printf (printf.c:34)
==31064==    by 0x401488: printDecodedMsg (Project2_lhuynh22_204.c:181)
==31064==    by 0x401679: decodeWords (Project2_lhuynh22_204.c:219)
==31064==    by 0x4017BC: decodeMsg (Project2_lhuynh22_204.c:242)
==31064==    by 0x401A26: main (Project2_lhuynh22_204.c:285)
==31064==  Address 0x590349f is 0 bytes after a block of size 15 alloc'd
==31064==    at 0x4C2BFB9: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:762)
==31064==    by 0x40153E: decodeWords (Project2_lhuynh22_204.c:195)
==31064==    by 0x4017BC: decodeMsg (Project2_lhuynh22_204.c:242)
==31064==    by 0x401A26: main (Project2_lhuynh22_204.c:285)
==31064==
```

Here is the parts where the error appear:

```
175 void printDecodedMsg(char **decoded, int wc){
176     int i;
177     for(i = 0; i < wc; i++)
178     |   printf("%s ", decoded[i]);
179 
180     printf("\n\n");
181 }
182 
183 void decodeWords(char **msgArr, int wc, char **wordArr, int cpWc){
184     char *str, *token, *search = ",", **decoded;
185     int i,j, row, col, charCount;
186 
187     decoded = calloc(wc, sizeof(char*));
188 
189     for(i = 0; i < wc; i++){
190     |   str = calloc(5000,sizeof(char));
191     |   strcpy(str, msgArr[i]);
192     |   decoded[i] = calloc(CHARMAX, sizeof(char));
193     |   token = strtok(str, search);
194     |   charCount = j = 0;
195     |   while(token != NULL){
196     |   |   if(charCount % 2 != 0){
197     |   |   |   col = atoi(token);
198     |   |   |   if(col >= CHARMAX){
199     |   |   |   |   printf("%s!!!The word does not have that many characters!!!", SPACES);
200     |   |   |   |   exit(-1);
201     |   |   |   }
202     |   |   |   decoded[i][j++] = wordArr[row][col];
203     |   |   }
204     |   |   else{
205     |   |   |   row = atoi(token);
206     |   |   |   if(row >= cpWc){
207     |   |   |   |   printf("%s!!!The cipher text does not have that many words!!!", SPACES);
208     |   |   |   |   exit(-1);
209     |   |   |   }
210     |   |   }
211     |   |   token = strtok(NULL, search);
212     |   |   charCount++;
213     |   }
214     |   free(str);
215     }
216     printDecodedMsg(decoded, wc);
217     freeMemChar(decoded, wc);
218 }
```

Comment: I think its better to show all the callers in the call stack with their arguments/parameters (i.e: where decodeWords is called and its parameters). Also the value of constants used in the code is not available from this segment of the code (i.e: CHARMAX)

Answer (score 0):

1. > printf("%s ", decoded[i]);

This is line, we are reading `decode[i]` array (close to line number 181)

2. > decoded[i] = calloc(CHARMAX, sizeof(char));

This is line, where we are allocating memory to `decode[i]` array (close to line number 195). Valgrind says, 15 bytes has been allocated .

3. You need to allocate enough memory for each `decode[i]` character array to store `\0` (Null) . For more information check this link :[https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/valgrind.php](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/%7Enewhall/unixhelp/valgrind.php)

PS: The value of CHARMAX is not known to provide an exact solution.  And the line numbers provided by valgrind may be different from the line numbers of editor (IDE).